# Deploying DBT pod on GKE / Kubernetes from Airflow using KubernetesPodOperator Error

Tags: python, kubernetes, airflow, google-kubernetes-engine, dbt

I'm trying to deploy a custom DBT pod using the KubernetesPodOperator package in Airflow 1.10.10

When I try to run the task in my Airflow I get this error:

> File
> "/home/airflow/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/kubernetes/config/incluster_config.py",
> line 51, in _load_config
> raise ConfigException("Service host/port is not set.")

I believe I have set the port already. Here is my KubernetesPodOperator task:

```
uk_dbt_transform_task = KubernetesPodOperator(
    name="dbt-test-processor",
    namespace='prod',
    project_id=PROJECT_ID,
    cluster_name=CLUSTER_NAME,
    location='europe-west2',
    startup_timeout_seconds=120,
    image=IMAGE_URL,
    cmds=["run"],
    arguments=["-s", "TABLE_NAME"],
    get_logs=True,
    image_pull_policy="Always",
    ports=9090, <---- here is the port I attached
    hostnetwork=False, <----- the host network is false as a default per the docs on airflow's site.
    is_delete_operator_pod=False, 
    config_file=KUBE_CONFIG,
    service_account_name=SERVICE_ACCOUNT,
    dag=dag,
    task_id='uk_dbt_transform_task'
)
```

I have set the variable in the task to '9090' the same I have exposed in the Dockerfile and [hostnetwork=False as per the docs](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.15/kubernetes.html).

Here is my docker file that I'm using to build the container, [it's exactly the same as the one given by DBT](https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/blob/main/docker/Dockerfile) but with a port exposed:

```
# Top level build args
ARG build_for=linux/amd64


# FROM python:3.9.16-bullseye
FROM --platform=$build_for python:3.9.16-bullseye as base


ARG dbt_core_ref=dbt-core@v1.4.0b1
ARG dbt_bigquery_ref=dbt-bigquery@v1.4.0b1

# System setup
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get dist-upgrade -y \
  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
    git \
    ssh-client \
    software-properties-common \
    make \
    build-essential \
    ca-certificates \
    libpq-dev \
  && apt-get clean \
  && rm -rf \
    /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    /tmp/* \
    /var/tmp/*

# Env vars
ENV PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8
ENV LANG=C.UTF-8

# Update python
RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel --no-cache-dir

# Set docker basics
WORKDIR /usr/app/dbt/
VOLUME /usr/app

COPY . /usr/app/dbt/
ENTRYPOINT ["dbt"]

##
# dbt-core
##
FROM base as dbt-core
RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir "git+https://github.com/dbt-labs/${dbt_core_ref}#egg=dbt-core&subdirectory=core"

##
# dbt-bigquery
##
FROM base as dbt-bigquery
RUN python -m pip install --no-cache-dir "git+https://github.com/dbt-labs/${dbt_bigquery_ref}#egg=dbt-bigquery"

# Expose port for dbt docs
EXPOSE 9090
```

Please help me I don't know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: If you are on GKE, perhaps the GKE-specific operator would be better? `from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.kubernetes_engine import GKEStartPodOperator`? I use a similar setup to you other than that and haven't experienced this error, so that's my best initial guess. [Docs here](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/using-gke-operator).

Comment: @PaddyAlton So apparently the Airflow version that I'm using doesn't have the Kubernetes_engine package. Here's the link to the docs. If you search GKE nothing comes up -> https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10/

Answer (score 0):

As @Paddy Alton mentioned, you can use [GKE operators](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/using-gke-operator).

A GKE operator runs pod in a specific cluster it can be a separate cluster which is not related to own environment

> A DAG that creates a Google Kubernetes Engine cluster with the
> `GKECreateClusterOperator`, uses the `GKEStartPodOperator` with the
> following configurations, and then deletes it with the
> `GKEDeleteClusterOperator` afterward:
>
> 1. Minimal configuration: Sets only the required parameters.
> 2. Template configuration: Uses parameters that you can template with Jinja.
> 3. Pod affinity configuration: Limits the available nodes to schedule pods on.
> 4. Full configuration: Includes all configurations.

Note- Use  the latest version of Cloud Composer

Also check this [Github](https://github.com/apache/airflow/discussions/15554) link to resolve the error.

Comment: So apparently the Airflow version that I'm using doesn't have the Kubernetes_engine package. Here's the link to the docs. If you search GKE nothing comes up -> airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.10